# How to make Cucumber generate steps with regex?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

For java, within eclipse, cucumber used to generate steps that looked like this:

```
@Then("the database attribute \"([^\"]*)\" is updated")
```

But now it generates steps like this:

```
@Then("the database attribute {string} is updated")
```

How can I go back to the old way of generation with regex?

Comment: show your feature file

Comment: @Alexey R. Gherkin is designed to be independent of one step from another. No step in my feature file can affect the regex generation, or function, or naming of any other (Unless they're exact duplicates). Plus, no portion of the feature file can change how eclipse generates this step other than the text I have already provided. https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber version **1.2.5** done that. now the latest version **6xx and 7xx**. Now we don't get the old way of styling. because cucumber plugin in eclipse and intellij migrated to latest one. please use latest version.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can point to this for my team lead and say for certain there's no way to go back after our version upgrade and we can start getting with the times!